# React Native notification/alert

Tags: react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, alert, react-native-notifications

In react native app
I want to implement a feature in which any employee whenever completes a certain task then reporting person should get notified
eg. Site visit, the employee checked in the app, etc.

So please guide me
How to implement this feature and which package should I use?

What I found till now

1. FCM
2. react-native-notifications
3. react-native-in-app-notification

Comment: You simply need cloud notification. Do you use a real-time database?

Comment: Yes,I am using real-time database & thanks for suggestion...

Comment: Check a new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a real-time database,  write a listener which dispatches an event with some payload data every time an employee accomplishes a task.

In this context, any local notification package can push local a notification for each event dispatched.

I recommend https://notifee.app/ for Local notification, It has easy API and more notification-related features.

In case you favor cloud over local notification. You should review https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/mobile-push-notifications-react-native. They have an easier-to-use API for pushing and receiving notifications.